# How to access directory of one application from another in microsoft azure?

Tags: azure

I have 2 different application deployed on Azure. First application of type webapi is used to upload files to the directory /doc/uploadedfiles of second application which is type webapp.

How to access basepath of second application from first application so that I can upload files to the /doc/uploadedfiles which is inside directory of second application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. App services don't have access to different app's directories, and you shouldn't really store any files there.

You should save those documents on Blob Storage, so you'll be able to access them from any application.

Comment: We have very large files, its not worth to store those files as Blob. We need to keep them inside directory of webapi. In that case how can I access webapi's directory from any application in order to use those files.